# How to run cleanup processes after a JMeter test?

Tags: jmeter

I would like to reset the server being tested (e.g. wipe sessions, reboot, etc.) for the next test.  How can I configure a test plan to run cleanup code (a single call to an appropriately configured HTTP Sampler would be enough) after all the test threads have completed?

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with your Test Plan Structure, by using two different thread groups.  Group A would run all the tests, then Group B would run the clean up.  Under "test plan" select the option to NOT run thread groups concurrently; thus B will execute after A completes.